# price not showing on front end virtuemart

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I have upgrade joomla and virtuemart afer upfrading joomla and virtuemart 3.0.6 price is not showing on front end, i do not know what going wrong with my code and my virtuemart configurations .
i have paste my code here for showing price.

```
if ($this->show_prices == '1') {

            if ($product->prices['salesPrice']<=0 and VmConfig::get ('askprice', 1) and  !$product->images[0]->file_is_downloadable) {

                echo JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_ASKPRICE');
            }
            //todo add config settings
            //echo $this->showBasePrice;
            if ($this->showBasePrice) {

                echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('basePrice', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_BASEPRICE', $product->prices);
                echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('basePriceVariant', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_BASEPRICE_VARIANT', $product->prices);

            }
            echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('variantModification', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_VARIANT_MOD', $product->prices);
            if (round($product->prices['basePriceWithTax'],$this->currency->_priceConfig['salesPrice'][1]) != $product->prices['salesPrice']) {

                echo '<div class="price-crossed" >' . $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('basePriceWithTax', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_BASEPRICE_WITHTAX', $product->prices) . "</div>";
            }
            if (round($product->prices['salesPriceWithDiscount'],$this->currency->_priceConfig['salesPrice'][1]) != $product->prices['salesPrice']) {

                echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPriceWithDiscount', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE_WITH_DISCOUNT', $product->prices);
            }
            echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE', $product->prices);
            if ($product->prices['discountedPriceWithoutTax'] != $product->prices['priceWithoutTax']) {
                echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('discountedPriceWithoutTax', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE_WITHOUT_TAX', $product->prices);
            } else {

                echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('priceWithoutTax', 'Price :  ', $product->prices);
            }
            echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('discountAmount', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_DISCOUNT_AMOUNT', $product->prices);
            echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('taxAmount', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_TAX_AMOUNT', $product->prices);
            $unitPriceDescription = JText::sprintf ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_UNITPRICE', $product->product_unit);
            echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('unitPrice', $unitPriceDescription, $product->prices);
        } ?>
```

Please anyone check this give me solution for this i am totally fadeup from this issue

Comment: Have you tried going line by line and finding out where it fails ? Does it even get inside of `if ($this->show_prices == '1') {`? And for sanity sake, shouldn't `'1`' just be `1` given that you're comparing an integer and not a string ? unless that field is a string and not an int..I'm rambling.

Comment: yes i have tried this and all going fine with this 1 but i do not what going wrong..

Comment: var_dump($product->prices); if it has right values, then there is a problem with the display. then start adding echos line by line to follow the flow of the code, so u can see where it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have also faced the same problem when i update my vm and joomla but after lots of searching i have found the solutions and it works for me.

I have follow 3 4 steps.

```
1. you have to update your vm tables through control panel
 Go to tools and migration->DB Tools
 under DB Tools there is option for Install/update vm  tables click on it and update vm tables structure.

2. After upgrading just tables called vm shopergroups and check field **custom_price_display** set to all field **0**
```

i have attached image for showing the right field[image]

You can try this i know this will help you and you find your solution